# Why my selectmenu's placeholder is not setting up with setAttribute selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, handlebars.js

When I click select menu all options appear. After that when i click on any option, with this below code I am trying its not setting the placeholder attribute with the selected option. What mistake I am doing?

```js
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").setAttribute("placeholder", text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sourcesSelect" id="sourcesSelect" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Select">
  <option class="custom-option "value="0">Requirement Completed</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="1">In Progress</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="2">Done</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="3">Approved</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="4">Revision Required</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="5">Live</option>
  <option class="custom-option value="6">Closed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is no `placeholder` attribute on a `select` element, so I'm not sure what behaviour you're expecting to see here. Can you edit the question to provide more clarity on your goal.

Comment: first you are missing `"` in html in class attribute, another point is instead of `click` use `change` event of `select`, and in option selected so what is use of place holder?

Comment: better to put `select` as first `disabled` option

Comment: how to bootstraopped design it?